# How to delete remote commit from bitbucket mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

How to delete a remote commit from bitbucket mercurial repository?

**Findings:** I could not found "Repository management" in the "Admin" section. which is mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/907319/1516512). Is this feature deprecated/dropped from bitbucket? If not where it is? Note that I am owner of the repository.

**Note for expert! only:** Remember I have already pushed my commit to bitbucket. I know deleting commit is not good, I am not interested to a backout my history by adding an extra commit. Moreover I can ensure you that someone will strip the commit manually from every local clone of this repo. So you don't have to be worried about this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On BitBucket, go to the overview page for the repository you're talking about.

There is a menu down the left hand side and at the bottom of it is an entry called **Settings**, click on that.
Then on the settings page there's an entry called **Strip Changesets** or  **Strip commits** where you can specify the revision to strip.

Remember that if the changeset you want to remove has child changesets that those will be stripped too.