# Can we undo pushed changes in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, commit, tortoisehg

I am using mercurial and have pushed some changes that I have to revert back. I didn't find any way to directly rollback that changes. I can remove my changes and commit it back but that would not be a right way to do that. Can anyone please suggest how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to login to the server and use the `hg strip` command.  If you cannot login to the server, you are out of luck; you can `hg backout` then push again, but this will leave the bad commits on the server along with the commit that undoes them.

For more details: [Mercurial: Remove changeset from remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907133/mercurial-remove-changeset-from-remote-branch)

Answer (score 0):

`hg revert -r .^ file-to-revert` followed by `hg commit` and `jf s` (if using jelly fish) that will remove the changeset from your diff.